# How to add marker with marker icon view in cluster manager on google map in swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I need to show marker with icon view on google map but marker is easily adding in cluster manager and marker with icon view is not adding. I don't have need to show info window on click of marker. I just need to show default marker icon view which is already opened.

```
for i in 0..<dataArr.count{

   let latitude = dataArr[i].lat ?? ""
   let longitude = dataArr[i].longs ?? ""

   let marker = GMSMarker()

   marker.position = 
     CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:CLLocationDegrees(latitude)!, 
     longitude: CLLocationDegrees(longitude)!)


   marker.userData = i

   marker.icon = UIImage(named: "CustomImage")
   marker.iconView = addressWindow //UIView type XIB

   let doubleLat = Double(latitude)
   let doubleLong = Double(longitude)

   let name = "Item \(i)"

  clusterDataArr.setValue("\(dataArr[i].id ?? "")", forKey: "Item \ 
 (i)")


 if let item = POIItem(position: 
 CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((doubleLat)!, (doubleLong)!), name: 
 name) as? POIItem{

             clusterManager.add(item)

             clusterManager.cluster()

       }

   }
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand your question completely. Are saying the marker is displayed and showing default icon instead of custom?

Comment: I face same issue with my android application. please help me if any solution you find...

Comment: No i need to show marker.iconView = UIView() in cluster manager in place of infoWindow. For iconView we don't need to tap on marker it is default opened but it is not adding in cluster manager